# notepad++ regex duplicate xml text on each line

Tags: notepad++, regex, xml

I need to process a xml file, in which a certain text has to be inserted (duplicated) - see the following, for an example:

```
<Item Property1="..." ... PropertyN="someText"></Item>
```

How I want it to look:

```
<Item Property1="..." ... PropertyN="someText">someText</Item>
```

The `someText`

1. doesn't have a fixed length (1 or more sentences/words)
2. can/may contain the followings:

   - &# xD; &# xA
   - (& amp; and _)
   - {0}{1}
   - /\~!@#%&*_+

My questions:

1. I've managed to find some of the groups (i.e. the text before PropertyN (`^.*?PropertyN="`) and the last group (i.e the one containing "> < /Item>" - `\"></Item>.*$`)) but I don't know how to extract the PropertyN value, how to integrate it and how to duplicate it.
2. How can I change the (replace with) regex so that a prefix and/or a suffix (constant in the entire file) are added for each copy of the someText? (for example I want "###prefix" and "###suffix" to be added so that the line looks like this)

   `<Item Property1="..." ... PropertyN="someText">###prefixsomeText###suffix</Item>`

Thank you!

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Item Property1=.+? PropertyN="([^"]+)">\K`
- Replace with: `###prefix$1###suffix`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Item Property1=    # literally
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
PropertyN="         # literally
([^"]+)             # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not double quote
">                  # end tag
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Replacement:**

```
###prefix           # prefix
$1                  # content of group 1, (some text)
###suffix           # suffix
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]